# BundleConfig não carrega todos os arquivos CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando carregar os arquivos CSS **jquery-ui.css** e **jquery-ui.theme.css** criando um bundles, mas o bundle insiste em carregar apenas o CSS padrão do ASP.NET MVC que **site.css**. Para funcionar, sempre tenho que carregar os arquivos CSS adicionais usando a tag `<link>`. Onde estou errando?

**BundleConfig**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dialogo.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
        }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @*<link href="~/Content/themes/base/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/css/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Menu Sistema</h2>

    @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Menu.cshtml")

    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Arquivos CSS**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há um pequeno erro de grafia na sua configuração. Note que seu Bundle está como:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
```

Pela sua imagem, deveria ser:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                "~/Content/themes/base/css/jquery-ui.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/css/jquery-ui.theme.css"));
    }
```

Comment: Cigano, eu fiz os ajustes e não funcionou. Acho que tem mais alguma coisa que fiz de errado.

Comment: Faltou. Editei a resposta. Veja agora.

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigada Cigano!